# Load data infile updating table on duplicate values from csv

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I'm trying to update mysql table based on my csv data where sha1 in my csv should update or insert the suggestedname on duplicate. What part am I doing wrong here? Gives me error:

```
ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where sha1=@col1' at line 1
```

**Here is my table structure:**

```
date_sourced, sha1, suggested, vsdt, trendx, falcon, notes, mtf
```

**CSV structure:**

```
SHA1,suggestedName
```

**Code:**

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
host='localhost',database='jeremy_db')

cursor = mydb.cursor()
query = "LOAD DATA INFILE %s IGNORE INTO TABLE jeremy_table_test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (@col1,@col2) set suggested=@col2 where sha1=@col1"
cursor.execute(query, (fullPath))
mydb.commit()
```

Comment: there is no `where` in `LOAD DATA INFILE`. you have to insert data into a similar table or into array, then update you `jeremy_table_test `

Answer (score 0):

`LOAD DATA INFILE` can not add condition in it. You can try to read file through pandas then insert value into table, but you need to set up an unique index on `sha1` in advance. otherwise, my script will not work([reason](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)).

```
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector as mysql

path = "1.xls"

df = pd.read_excel(path)

_sha1 = df["SHA1"].tolist()
_suggestedName = df["suggestedName"].tolist()

conn = mysql.connect(user="xx",passwd="xx",db="xx")
cur = conn.cursor()

sql = """INSERT INTO jeremy_table_test (sha1,suggested) VALUES (%s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE suggested=VALUES(suggested)"""

try:
    cur.executemany(sql,list(zip(_sha1,_suggestedName)))
    conn.commit()
except Exception as e:
    conn.rollback()
    raise e
```